# Merging Line Segments to Eliminate Non-Junction Nodes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, editing, polyline-creation

I’m working with USGS NHDFlowline datasets (polylines representing US rivers and streams). I want to merge some of the line features so that nodes only occur at tributary junctions. For a generalized example, see the attached picture. I want to merge lines 1, 2, 3, and 4, thereby eliminating nodes 2, 3, and 4 while preserving nodes 1 and 5. Similarly, I want to merge lines 5 and 6, eliminating node 6 while preserving nodes 1 and 7.

I need an automated way to do this in QGIS 3.2 for a polyline containing > 10^4 features. Any suggestions? [image]

Comment: 1 to 4 are 4 line features? Do they share some common attribute?

Comment: Yes, green labels 1-4 are four line features contained in the same .shp file. Red labels are nodes. The line features all have the same attribute fields, though I don't know if any of those fields will be useful for identifying which features to merge.

Comment: Perhaps you can try joining all the lines together then using GRASS v.clean with the break option. It should break lines at the intersection point.

Comment: The procedure proposed by Techie_Gus works in principle, but there is still an issue. I selected all the line features at once and created a new, merged layer (with only 1 line feature) by going to “Edit - Edit Geometry - Merge Selected Features”. However, the v.clean break tool does not correctly break the merged layer at every junction. It seems to miss about 10% of the junctions. I’m not sure why this is. The break tool does not use a spatial threshold, and I don’t know which other criteria I could adjust to help identify the remaining junctions. Any thoughts?

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps there is a way to identify junctions based on the number of lines shared by each node? By definition, a junction occurs at a node shared by 3 or more lines. Is there a way to A. loop through the nodes and identify those shared by 3 or more lines, and subsequently B. merge all lines connected between those nodes?